# What does this regex do in conjuction with this list-comprehension?

Tags: python, regex, list-comprehension

I am looking through some code and would like to know what the following patch does. I am especially interested in the first two lines of code.

```
non_printable_re = re.compile(ur'(?:%s)' % '|'.join(
    [ chr(i) for i in range(1,31) if i != 10 ]))
obj_txt = lobj.get_text()
obj_txt = non_printable_re.sub( '', obj_txt)
obj_txt = obj_txt.strip()
```

I know what the regex symbols themselves represent but i am having a hard time figuring out what it does in combination with the list-comprehension...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target of this code is to remove characters that are not printable

Looking at in split to part:

1. First we create a list of characters that are "non-printable" (first 31 letters of the ASCII table

```py
print([ chr(i) for i in range(1,31) if i != 10 ])
['\x01', '\x02', '\x03', '\x04', '\x05', '\x06', '\x07', '\x08', '\t', '\x0b', '\x0c', '\r', '\x0e', '\x0f', '\x10', '\x11', '\x12', '\x13', '\x14', '\x15', '\x16', '\x17', '\x18', '\x19', '\x1a', '\x1b', '\x1c', '\x1d', '\x1e']
```

2. Then create a regex that matches any of these characters

```
'(?:\x01|\x02|\x03|\x04|\x05|\x06|\x07|\x08|\t|\x0b|\x0c|\r|\x0e|\x0f|\x10|\x11|\x12|\x13|\x14|\x15|\x16|\x17|\x18|\x19|\x1a|\x1b|\x1c|\x1d|\x1e)'
```

Then replace every one of these characters with '' (removing it)

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation , i get it now :)